# limite sqlite database entries

Tags: android, sqlite

I have a table called "catory" in my sqlite database that contains some pre defined categories : how can i limit the number of entries to these pre defined entries (there s 8 categories so I have to limit it to 8)

Does anyone know how to do that with sqlite :s ?

Comment: are you talking about limiting the user to using one of the 8 catagories when they are entering data?

Comment: Just don't provide a method for the user to update that table.

Comment: Yes but i d like it to be more secured, if a user manages to do an sql insertion or something :s ...

Comment: "if a user manages to do an sql insertion or something".  They can't, unless you provide them a method in your app to do it.  On an android device, the only app with access to your DB is yours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the table in a spinner in your data entry page and then all the user can do is select one of those.

Comment: Isn t it possible to put a kind of trigger or something in the ddl database ?